# How to remove a webpack module rule pre compilation?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I'm using webpack 5 and am merging several webpack configurations using the `webpack-merge` library, and in one case I'm getting a result that has two competing rules. In other words, they both test for the same regex but the loader details are different.

The first is for production:

```
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
```

The second is for development only:

```
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Resulting in...

```
...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
   }
...
```

What I'd like to do is get rid of one of them during (or pre) compilation.

I looked into using the webpack hooks but without success. I'm not sure if they're even the right tool for the job.

I also looked into the `webpack-chain` library, but it seems like overkill for what I need. Plus as I understand it, it would require I re-rewrite all my webpack confgs into its format.

Is there a simple way to modify configs with a callback or something?“

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a webpack hook for this. Here's my solution:

```
module.exports = class DevRefreshRuleUpdatePlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.watchRun.tap('DevRefreshRuleUpdatePlugin', compiler => {
      const rules = compiler.options.module.rules.filter(rule => {
        if (!rule.test.toString().match(/\.\(ts\|js\)x\?\$/)) return rule;
      });

      const updatedRules = [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: [require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        ...rules
      ];

      compiler.options.module.rules = updatedRules;
    });
  }
};
```